# Looping a function that changes it's output every iteration

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm trying to create something that if the number is odd for example 7 it does this (7 * 3+1) and if it is even for example 6 it does this (6/2) but the problem is that    I want to loop this but it updates the number every output from the example earlier 7 I want this to turn to (22/2) and so on and if the number 1 is reached it stops.

```
output = []
number = 7
def mat(self):

   if (self % 2) == 0:
      even = self / 2
      return even
   else:
      odd = self * 3 + 1
      return odd



while mat(number) != 1:
   output.append(mat(number))
   output.append(mat(mat(number))
   

print(output)
```

this part doesn't work because it will never reach 1 and it only has 1 output (22) starting from the number 7  :

```
   while mat(number) != 1:
   output.append(mat(number))
   output.append(mat(mat(number))
```

Comment: You need to assign the return value of `mat(number)` back to `number`.

Comment: If you're using Python 3.8 or later, you can use `while (number := mat(number)) != 1: output.append(number)` for your whole loop.

Comment: This seems like a recursion thing. Is there a reason you arent using recursion? Also why are you having the while loop outside the function if you would want it to be done internally from the function? I get youre goal but im having trouble understanding your setup and the reason for it.

Answer (score 3):

To update `number`, you need to assign it:

```
number = mat(number)
```

The best place to do this is in the while loop:

```
while number != 1:
    number = mat(number)
```

For an exercise like this, it makes sense to just print the value on each iteration rather than trying to create an array of results:

```
while number != 1:
    print(number)
    number = mat(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update the value

For while loop:

```
a = 0
while a<10:
    print("Hello World")
    a = a + 1
```

For for loop:

```
a = 0
for i in range(10):
    print("Hello World")
    a = a + 1
    if a >= 10:
        break
```